# Warning while install-module PowerShellGet

Tags: powershell

While installing PowerShellGet, I perform the following:

```
Install-PackageProvider Nuget –force –verbose
```

then I Exit, try running the following:

```
Install-Module –Name PowerShellGet –Force –Verbose
```

When I do this, I get the error:
[image: Error with install-module]

This error occurs when I try to install other modules too, like MSOnline, Azure etc. 
I have the latest version of Powershell and also the necessary modules. 
I feel that the reason is due to the PowershellGet file.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the PowerShell repository before installing PowerShellGet. Try this

```
Register-PSRepository -Name “PSGallery” -SourceLocation “https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/" -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

Comment: Tried doing this too, which doesn't seem to work. "parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameter" error is obtained.